# Need ifconfig help

Tags: ifconfig

I'm a complete noob at Ubuntu. I'm having to do some work on it, and was told to explain what happens when you type in the command "ifconfig", but I have no idea what single thing of this means. Please explain to me, in the most understandable way possible, what any of the below means:

```
eth9      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:cc:6a:3f:37:64  
          inet addr:10.170.148.199  Bcast:10.170.151.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4ecc:6aff:fe3f:3764/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:49704 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:94 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4871401 (4.8 MB)  TX bytes:21656 (21.6 KB)
```

Comment: Somehow this 'smeels' like homework for school.  You can try by starting to read the man page of ifconfig, as it explains what ifconfig can be used for. Open a terminal and enter `man ifconfig`. Man pages are common tools to give manuals to us users.

Comment: Wiki has some basic informations as well - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, while I have the suspicion you are asking us a homework question, here we go.

```
eth9      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:cc:6a:3f:37:64
```

- The interface (network card, NIC for short) is known as `eth9` to the
  operating system.
- The type of the interface is `Ethernet`.
- The hardware address, or MAC address of your NIC is `4c:cc:6a:3f:37:64`

  ```
        inet addr:10.170.148.199  Bcast:10.170.151.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
  ```

These are the IPv4 settings associated to the NIC

- Your IPv4 is a private address `10.170.148.199`
- Your broadcast address is `10.170.151.255`
- Your netmask is `255.255.252.0`, which basically means that your local network will have the last digit vary between 1 and 254

  ```
        inet6 addr: fe80::4ecc:6aff:fe3f:3764/64 Scope:Link
  ```
- This is your local IPv6 address (`fe80::4ecc:6aff:fe3f:3764/64`).  These are local only.
- Scope: Link -> Not sure, but from what I understand the IPv6 is limited to the link

  ```
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  ```
- UP ->  NIC is up
- BROADCAST -> NIC can broadcast to the network
- RUNNING -> I don't know
- MULTICAST -> NIC can do multicast

MTU stands for "Maximum transmission unit" and is the largest packet that may be used on the NIC.
Metric:  A number indicating the weight of using this NIC.  This is useful for routing.  (A lower metric will be preferred over a higher metric.  You could, for example, set a more expensive line to a higher Metric)

```
          RX packets:49704 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:94 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4871401 (4.8 MB)  TX bytes:21656 (21.6 KB)
```

Transmission statistics.
RX -> Received
TX -> Transmitted